# nearbySearch with name specified like wildcard

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am after a way to do a Google Maps API V3 "nearbySearch" by specifying both an exact location but *not* an exact store name (like a wildcard search).

e.g., If the request was for "Starbucks" in "San Francisco" it would return all Places called "Starbucks", whether the Place had more words in it's title or not e.g., results would contain "Starbucks Coffee", "Starbucks Smith St" or simply "Starbucks". Currently it looks like it only finds identical matches, "Starbucks".

**Code** ([more info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)):

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {

  // Specify lat/lng of search location
  var SanFran = new google.maps.LatLng(37.777119,-122.41964);

  // Create new map object
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: SanFran,
    zoom: 15
  });

  // Create request parametres
  var request = {
    location: SanFran
    , radius: '500',
    , name: "Starbucks"
  };

  // Call the nearby search using the parametres
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

}

// Asynchronous marker creation at returned locations
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I've done some reading and whilst it looks like API3 doesn't offer Wildcard search, I'm hoping there are work arounds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry all, the answer was really quite simple. I should have been using the textSearch rather than nearbySearch:

```js
...

// Create request parametres
var request = {
  location: SanFran
  , radius: '500',
  , query: "Starbucks"
};

// Call the nearby search using the parametres
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);

...
```

More info here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests